# Wanted a java library for parse string formula

Tags: java, parsing, variables, expression, formula

This is my first post here. So sorry if i doing so wrong.

My task is get variables list from string formula like a "A + B * (C - 21.2) / DD".
I have found solution in Apache Jexl lib. This work exactly what I need.

```
JexlEngine engine = new JexlEngine();
Set<List<String>> exactlyWhatINeed = engine.createScript("A+B+C/D").getVariables()
```

This provide list of parsed variables for me, perfect.

BUT i have one big trouble. My variables can be written on russian language. 
So formula can be like a "23 - О + ПАНЬКИ * simpleANSI_Var". This library throw an exception, coz variables name must be in ANSI between 32 and 127.

I need something similar, spended two days for googlesearch and testing. I'm so tired, help me if anyone know the solution. I need just a var's list, i know how to execute this and get result via Script Engine or another libs like a JEval.

Thank you in advance, friends. 
And yes. Sorry for my pretty bad English.

Comment: Have you considered cheating? He's what I'd do: Every time I came across an unparsable character, I'd replace it with an ANSI character and keep the values mapped together, then after the library has processed the new version, remap the Russian characters.

Comment: @MrLore What if formula will contain Russian character and ANSI character that would be used to replace it?

Comment: Yes, formula can contain Russian and English characters. This is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, this is the sort of solution I was envisioning:

```
class HaxlEngine
{
    static boolean isANSI(final char c)
    {
        return c <= 0x7F;
    }

    public static Set<List<String>> doSum(String formula)
    {
        JexlEngine engine = new JexlEngine();
        final Map<Character, Character> mappedChars = new HashMap<>();
        char ansiCounter = 'A';
        for(final char c : formula.toCharArray())
        {
            if(!isANSI(c))
            {
                char newValue;
                do
                {
                    newValue = ansiCounter++;
                }
                while(formula.contains(String.valueOf(newValue)));
                mappedChars.put(c, newValue);
                formula = formula.replace(c, newValue);
            }
        }
        final Set<List<String>> exactlyWhatINeed = engine.createScript(formula).getVariables();
        for(final List<String> list : exactlyWhatINeed)
        {
            for(String str : list)
            {
                for(final Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : mappedChars.entrySet())
                {
                    str = str.replace(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        return exactlyWhatINeed;
    }                                                       
}
```

This will check every character in the formula you give it, and replace any characters which aren't valid ANSI characters with standard `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. I couldn't test the actual engine part, however the replacements seem to work in my tests (see below), so I believe it will work when you plug in the library.

```
static boolean isANSI(final char c)
{
    return c <= 0x7F;
}


static String testReplaceNonANSI(String maybeANSI)
{
    final Map<Character, Character> mappedChars = new HashMap<>();
    char ansiCounter = 'A';
    for(final char c : maybeANSI.toCharArray())
    {
        if(!isANSI(c))
        {
            char newValue;
            do
            {
                newValue = ansiCounter++;
            }
            while(maybeANSI.contains(String.valueOf(newValue)));
            mappedChars.put(c, newValue);
            maybeANSI = maybeANSI.replace(c, newValue);
        }
    }
    return maybeANSI;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String a = "(A+B/C) * X";
    String b = "(О+А/C) * П";
    System.out.println(testReplaceNonANSI(a)); //(A+B/C) * X
    System.out.println(testReplaceNonANSI(b)); //(A+B/C) * C
}
```

Comment: And what we got? 2nd expression have 4 different var's and after converting П transform in C. This different var's with different values. And variables name can be long, like 5-6 characters in name. Counter may go out of bounds

Comment: @АндрейКрюков It changes them back to the original characters in the output.

Comment: But Script will return three var's for me: A, B, C. But original expr has four var's. And convert it back will return "(О+А/П) * П" not a original "(О+А/C) * П"